# Is "System.Speech.Recognition" namespace available in mono framework?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, speech-to-text

I am building one speech recognition app using classes available in .net framework. My client wants to run this application in Linux using mono framework.

I tried to search whether this particular namespace and its related classes are available and working in mono framework too but couldn't find 100% correct answer.

So I have two questions in my mind :

1. Whether this `System.Speech.Recognition` namespace is available in mono?
2. How to check if particular namespace/feature/class present in .net is available in mono?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of mono, see this link for what's available in Mono compared to the .NET framework: http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Speech

So, yes, there seems to be a System.Speech.Recognition namespace available in the Mono framework, and it actually seems complete. I've never used it though.

Comment: This has been proven to be a wrong answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086093/how-do-you-access-the-system-speech-framework-in-monodevelop