# How do you access the System.Speech framework in monodevelop?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

Related: [Is "System.Speech.Recognition" namespace available in mono framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644214/is-system-speech-recognition-namespace-available-in-mono-framework)

I'm aware that the System.Speech namespace is available in mono according to this [link](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Speech) but I'm not sure how to access it using MonoDevelop.  When I try to add a reference to the namespace under Projects > Edit References, System.Speech is just not there.  Whenever I try to build with the keyword `using System.Speech` I'm given the error:

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Speech' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (Assembly-CSharp).
```

I'm running OSX but I'm under the impression that mono is a full implementation of the .NET framework so I should be able to access it, since I can access other .NET libraries.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you have misunderstood the charts,

http://go-mono.com/status/

The first column is for .NET 4.0 vs .NET 4.5, which is purely the comparison of Microsoft's stuffs. Thus, System.Speech is listed there.

You can see that when Mono's stuffs are compared to Microsoft's, System.Speech is not listed.

That simply indicates Mono does not yet attack in this area, and which is meaningful. System.Speech heavily relies on Microsoft's speech engine inside Microsoft Windows platforms, which Mono is not easy to clone on other platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clears a lot up for me, I read a whole bunch of other questions and people kept pointing at that [link](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Speech) as saying that mono _has_ implemented `System.Speech` and the title (Mono System.Speech in 4.0 vs MS.NET 4.5) seems a little misleading, but I totally just read it wrong :).  Also, you're right the [status page](http://go-mono.com/status/) clearly says that it's just .NET 4.0 vs. .NET 4.5! Thanks a bunch!!!!

Comment: This has got to be the most confusing status page I have ever seen.