# compile cs code in mono appears this error Unexpected symbol SpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: .net, mono

HOw I could solve this error

I use this command

```
mcs -out:hello.exe hello.cs
```

Please help me

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
      SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
      synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
      synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
      Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Hm, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21087206/2086717 Mono does not include the `System.Speech.dll` assembly. Maybe that's the reason for the error?

Comment: yes could be this the error